# How to find the offset for a polygon Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am making a polygon from lines.

```
   x = options.e.pageX - offset.left;
   y = options.e.pageY - offset.top;
```

On click, I capture mouse position. After, I add that point to array of points.

```
roofPoints.push(new Point(x, y));

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

When all points are set I do this:

`var roof = new fabric.Polyline(roofPoints, {
            fill : 'purple',
        });`

The problem with this is that while I set points I am drawing lines for the polygon like so:

```
var points = [ x, y, x, y ];
        lines.push(new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth : 1,
            selectable : false,
            stroke : 'red'
        }).setOriginX(x).setOriginY(y));
```

So basically I'm making a counter of a polygon and when I'm done drawing the counter, I just create a polygon. But the problem is that when I create polygon it doesn't fit in the counter it just moves away from the counter. I have tried to find how to correctly offset it.

`roof.set({
            left : left,
            top : top,
        });`

I was trying to get left upper point of a bounding rectangle for the polygon and to set it so it places correctly. But that din't work. This how it looks [image]

And a fiddle [How it looks](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Xth/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I checked coords of created polygon and saw that it has recalculated them somehow and that's why it was offset. For example:

> PointBefore
>   58 | 193
>   PointAfter
>   -189 | -52

This is how it changes, so to make the correct offset all I did was get it before I create the polygon and set top and left after it has been created.

```
 var left = findLeftPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
    var top = findTopPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
    var roof = new fabric.Polyline(roofPoints, {
        fill: 'purple'
    });
    roof.set({
        left: left,
        top: top
    });


    return roof;
```

And a [fiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Xth/3/).

Answer (score 0):

This script doesn't work on 1.4.13 and 1.5.0 fabricjs versions. Cannot confirm on previus versions.

EDIT: Fixed the problem, also in later versions:

Change this:

```
var points = [ x, y, x, y ];
    lines.push(new fabric.Line(points, {
        strokeWidth : 1,
        selectable : false,
        stroke : 'red'
    }).setOriginX(x).setOriginY(y));
```

into this:

```
 var points = [ x, y, x, y ];
    lines.push(new fabric.Line(points, {
        strokeWidth : 1,
        selectable : false,
        stroke : 'red'
    }));
```